# Shared SQL Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql

I have a Windows Hyper VPS plan with 1024 MB of RAM. After installing SQL Server 2008 Express, my memory usage went up to 75% without running my site yet. I know that SQL Server consumes a lot of memory, so I decided to host my DB on a shared server.

Which of the following is more scalable: install my DB on my VPS, or on a shared server ?

If the latter, then can you recommend me a good shared server?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

SQL will consume up to about 90% of free memory regardless of how active it is, how much data it has, or the queries you throw at it. It's probably best to try the configuration you have now and stress test it to see how it performs. Then make a decision based on the results of that testing.

Comment: Does it do it by default because of the large page cache setting in the secpol.msc ?